# How do you add New Product to Existing Category using Admin Panel?

Tags: product

How do you add New Product to Existing Category using Admin Panel? For example, I know how to add the product and image, but now that the product is added, how or where do you set the new product to "existing category" using admin panel? Can you please point me to where this is in manual, or if there's a link to step-by-step how-to?

Answer (score 1):

When viewing a product in the Admin panel, on the left hand side should be a tab labeled 'Categories' that lets you assign it to existing categories.

Important to note your product needs to be enabled & visible to appear on the front end of your site.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log into admin
2. Go to `Catalog  >  Manage Categories`.
3. Now you can see a category tree in the left side. Select the appropriate category.
4. There are 4 tabs available for each category. Click on `Display Settings` tab. Set `Dispaly Mode` to either `Product only` or `Static Blocks and Products`.
5. Now click on `Category Products` tab. Put any number of products from the available grid list.
6. Save all update.
7. Clear all cache.
8. Reload the category page again.

You are done.

**Suggestion:-** Please read magento user guide well. This appears to be very very basic question.[**Go here**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide)  :)